# is there a better way to check every multidimensional array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

i make a program that convert json to php and check every value of multidimensional array with foreach loop  and if a value equal to certain condition it delete that key and value and convert it back to json. iam trying to make this with less code.

i use nested foreach loop to check every array's value. i give it condition like if value = 0 or empty string or null then delete it but it take too many line of code. its not good method for too many multidimensional array so i was looking for better solution

this is my json

```
{
    "UniqueId": "PO3589472",
    "FareType": 2,
    "BookedBy": "Api ",
    "OrderBy": "Api ",
    "ClientBalance": 0,
    "Error": null,
    "Success": true,
    "TktTimeLimit": "2022-08-10T14:11:45",
    "Category": 21,
    "Status": 21,
    "RefundMethod": 1,
    "TravelItinerary": {
        "ItineraryInfo": {
            "ItineraryPricing": {
                "BaseFare": 8469250,
                "ServiceTax": 0,
                "TotalTax": 993000,
                "TotalFare": 9462250,
                "TotalCommission": 0,
                "Currency": "IRR"
            },
            "CustomerInfoes": [
                {
                    "Customer": {
                        "Gender": 0,
                        "PassengerType": 1,
                        "PassportNumber": "",
                        "NationalId": "1829961233",
                        "Nationality": "IR",
                        "DateOfBirth": "1996-07-08T00:00:00",
                        "PassportExpireDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                        "PassportIssueCountry": "IR",
                        "PassportIssueDate": "2022-08-10T00:00:00",
                        "PaxName": {
                            "PassengerFirstName": "MAJID",
                            "PassengerMiddleName": null,
                            "PassengerLastName": "MAJIDIFAR",
                            "PassengerTitle": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "ETickets": "8151405444745",
                    "ETicketNumbers": [
                        {
                            "ETicketNumber": "8151405444745",
                            "EticketStatus": 1,
                            "IsRefunded": false,
                            "DateOfIssue": "2022-08-10T13:58:47",
                            "AirlinePnr": "TXNXM",
                            "TotalRefund": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "ReservationItems": [
                {
                    "AirEquipmentType": "737",
                    "AirlinePnr": "TXNXM",
                    "ArrivalAirportLocationCode": "ABD",
                    "ArrivalDateTime": "2022-08-17T23:25:00",
                    "ArrivalTerminal": "",
                    "Baggage": "20KG",
                    "DepartureAirportLocationCode": "THR",
                    "DepartureDateTime": "2022-08-17T22:05:00",
                    "DepartureTerminal": "Terminal 4",
                    "FlightNumber": "3750",
                    "JourneyDuration": "01:20",
                    "JourneyDurationPerMinute": 0,
                    "MarketingAirlineCode": "EP",
                    "OperatingAirlineCode": "EP",
                    "ResBookDesigCode": "Y",
                    "StopQuantity": 0,
                    "IsCharter": false,
                    "TechnicalStops": [],
                    "IsReturn": false,
                    "CabinClassCode": 1
                }
            ],
            "TripDetailPtcFareBreakdowns": [
                {
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": {
                        "PassengerType": 1,
                        "Quantity": 1
                    },
                    "TripDetailPassengerFare": {
                        "BaseFare": 8469250,
                        "ServiceTax": 0,
                        "Tax": 993000,
                        "TotalFare": 9462250,
                        "Commission": 0,
                        "Currency": "IRR"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "PhoneNumber": "09359276735",
            "Email": "info@iran-tech.com",
            "ItineraryFareFamily": null
        },
        "BookingNotes": [],
        "Services": []
    },
    "ValidatingAirlineCode": "EP",
    "DirectionInd": 1,
    "OnlineCheckIn": false,
    "AirRemark": [],
    "curl_error": false
}
```

this is my foreach loop code

```
<?php
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("test_php.json");
    $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    

    foreach($json as $keys1 => $values1){
        if($values1 == 0 || $values1 == "" || $values1 == "Api " || !isset($values1) ){
            unset($json[$keys1]);
        }else{
            if(is_array($values1)){
                foreach($values1 as $keys2 => $values2){
                    if($values2 == 0 || $values2 == "" || $values2 == "Api " || !isset($values2) ){
                        unset($json[$keys1][$keys2]);
                    }else{
                        if(is_array($values2)){
                            foreach($values2 as $keys3 => $values3){
                                if($values3 == 0 || $values3 == "" || $values3 == "Api " || !isset($values3) ){
                                    unset($json[$keys1][$keys2][$keys3]);
                                }else{
                                    if(is_array($values3)){
                                        foreach($values3 as $keys4 => $values4){
                                            if($values4 == 0 || $values4 == "" || $values4 == "Api " || !isset($values4) ){
                                                unset($json[$keys1][$keys2][$keys3][$keys4]);
                                            }else{
                                                if(is_array($values4)){
                                                    foreach($values4 as $keys5 => $values5){
                                                        if($values5 == 0 || $values5 == "" || $values5 == "Api " || !isset($values5) ){
                                                            unset($json[$keys1][$keys2][$keys3][$keys4][$keys5]);
                                                        }else{
                                                            if(is_array($values5)){
                                                                foreach($values5 as $keys6 => $values6){
                                                                    if($values6 == 0 || $values6 == "" || $values6 == "Api " || !isset($values6) ){
                                                                        unset($json[$keys1][$keys2][$keys3][$keys4][$keys5][$keys6]);
                                                                    }else{
                                                                        if(is_array($values6)){
                                                                            foreach($values6 as $keys7 => $values7){
                                                                                if($values7 == 0 || $values7 == "" || $values7 == "Api " || !isset($values7) ){
                                                                                    unset($json[$keys1][$keys2][$keys3][$keys4][$keys5][$keys6][$keys7]);
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $path = "test_php(final).json";
    $converter = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    // print_r($v);
    $open = fopen($path, 'w');
    fwrite($open, $converter);
    fclose($open);
    // print_r($json);
?>
```

Comment: Use a recursive function so you don't have to repeat the loop for every level.

Comment: Recursion is the answer, but you should be on the lookout for "arrow pattern" code like this. [See how it's pointing off the side of your screen?] It is frequently a signal that you're coding yourself into a corner.

Comment: can someone show me article website or video about delete multidimensional array value in recursive way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is the answer, and it will look something like:

```php
function clean_array($input) {
  $out = []
  foreach($input as $key => $value) {
    if( is_array($value) ) {
      $out[$key] = clean_array($value);
    } else {
      if( $value == '' || ... ) {
        continue;
      }
      $out[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $out;
  }
}
```